# How to add map into the same struct which is used to deserialize json configs?

Tags: json, go, struct

I am working on deserializing `json` into a struct as shown below and it works fine.

```
type DataConfigs struct {
    ClientMetrics []Client `json:"ClientMetrics"`
}

type Client struct {
    ClientId  int  `json:"clientId"`
    .....
    .....
}

const (
    ConfigFile = "clientMap.json"
)

func ReadConfig(path string) (*DataConfigs, error) {
    files, err := utilities.FindFiles(path, ConfigFile)
  // check for error here
  
    var dataConfig DataConfigs
    body, err := ioutil.ReadFile(files[0])
  // check for error here
    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &dataConfig)
  // check for error here

    return &dataConfig, nil
}
```

Now I am trying to build a map of `integer` and `Client` using `DataConfigs` object that was created as shown above in the code. So I created a method to do the job as shown below and I modified `ReadConfig` method to do that too.

```
func ReadConfig(path string, logger log.Logger) (*DataConfigs, error) {
  files, err := utilities.FindFiles(path, ConfigFile)
  // check for error here
  
  var dataConfig DataConfigs
  body, err := ioutil.ReadFile(files[0])
  // check for error here
  err = json.Unmarshal(body, &dataConfig)
  // check for error here

  idx := BuildIndex(dataConfig)
  // now how to add this idx and dataConfig object in one struct?
  
  return &dataConfig, nil
}

func BuildIndex(dataConfig DataConfigs) map[int]Client {
    m := make(map[int]Client)
    for _, dataConfig := range dataConfig.ClientMetrics {
        m[dataConfig.ClientId] = dataConfig
    }
    return m
}
```

My confusion is - Should I modify `DataConfigs` struct to add `idx` map too and then return that struct from `ReadConfig` method or should I create a new struct to handle that?

Basically I want to return `DataConfigs` struct which has `ClientMetrics` array along with `idx` map. How can I do this here? I am slightly confuse because I started with `golang` recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically a design question with multiple options. First, I would avoid adding the map to your original DataConfigs type since it does not match the json representation. This could lead to confusion down the road.

Which option to choose depends on your requirements and preferences. Some ideas from the top of my head:

1. Have you considered returning the map only? After all, you've got every Client in your map. If you need to iterate all Clients you can iterate all values of your map.
2. Second option is to return the map in addition to DataConfigs. Go allows to return multiple values from a function as you already do for error handling.
3. Finally, you could wrap DataConfigs and your map in a new simple struct type as you already guessed.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion so if I return map then I do need another struct basically with just the map in it right and then construct that struct with map in it after deserializing?

Comment: Any idea on this?

Comment: I am not sure why you want a struct because you already have all data from DataConfigs inside the map. You could just use the map for further processing. Of course, one could also wrap the map in a struct or combine both the Client slice and the map in a new struct type like this:
```type ConfigLookup struct {
 ClientMetrics []Client
 IdToClient map[int]Client
}
...
func ReadConfig(path string, logger log.Logger) (*ConfigLookup, error) {
...
  return &ConfigLookup{dataConfig.ClientMetrics, idx}, nil
}```